# Evaluating the resulted simulated data

Tags: r, probability, sampling, statistical-sampling

I am simulating data using *the Rejection method* where the density function of `X` is given by `f(x)= C * e^(x) for all x in [0,1]`. I defined `g(x) = 1` and `C` to be the maximum of `f(x)` which is equal to `1/(e-1)`.

I used the following code to simulate data:

```
rejection <- function(f, C, g, rg, n) {
  naccepts <- 0
  result.sample <- rep(NA, n)

  while (naccepts < n) {
    y <- rg(1)
    u <- runif(1)

    if ( u <= f(y) / (C*g(y)) ) {
      naccepts <- naccepts + 1
      result.sample[naccepts] = y
    }
  }

  result.sample
}

f <- function(x) ifelse(x>=0 & x<=1, (exp(x)), 0)
g <- function(x) 1
rg <- runif
C <-  1/(exp(1) -1)

result <- rejection(f, C, g,rg, 1000)
```

Then, I use the `histogram` to compare the simulated data with the `curve` of original `pdf` as

```
hist(result,freq = FALSE)
curve(f, 0, 1, add=TRUE)
```

But the resulted plot is kind of weired! [the plot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm3sA.png) so I am looking for any help to clarify what is wrong in my work.

Comment: It is correct, but you need to extend the y axis.  `f` on (0,1) goes from 1 to e - the left end of it appears on the chart.  Of course that might not be what you are intending to plot!

Comment: @AndrewGustar but why the sampled data don't match the curve? and as you see, when using the modification in the answer below, there i a huge difference between the curve and the histogram

Comment: Are you dividing by `C` when you should be multiplying, in the `if` statement in your loop?

Comment: @AndrewGustar +1. You found it, this was the problem

Answer (score 0):

This shows the whole curve and histogram:

```
curve(f, 0, 1)
hist(result,freq = FALSE, add=TRUE)
```

But of course now the histogram is somewhat small in the plot...

Comment: thanks, or there is something wrong on my code  and I don't know what it is

Comment: This is the normal behaviour of base `plot`. The first call to `plot` defines the size (i.e. the zoom level) of the plot. By drawing the plot with the wider range of values first we make sure everything fits

Comment: Yes I understand this part but I am wondering why there is no matching between the histogram and the curve

Comment: ah, ok.. yea to me it does not look like that curve has an integral of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your maximum value is wrong. For exp(x) in the range [0...1] interval, normalized PDF would be

```
f(x) = exp(x)/(exp(1) - 1)
```

Thus maximum of f(x) is exp(1)/(exp(1) - 1)

UPDATE

Ok, here is code which follows wiki article on [Rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)

```
sampleRej <- function(f, g, rg, M, n) { # rejection sampling following wiki
    naccepts <- 0
    result   <- rep(NA, n)

    while (naccepts < n) {
        y <- rg(1)
        u <- runif(1)

        if ( u <= f(y) / (M*g(y)) ) {
            naccepts <- naccepts + 1
            result[naccepts] = y
        }
    }

    result
}

g <- function(x) { # Normalized uniform distribution PDF
    1.0
}

f <- function(x) { # normalized sampling PDF
    exp(x)/(exp(1.0) - 1.0)
}

rg <- function(n) { # function to sample from g, which is uniform
    runif(n)
}


M <- exp(1.0)/(exp(1.0) - 1.0) # f(x) maximum value
q <- sampleRej(f, g, rg, M, 100000) # sample 100K points

# and plot everything together
curve(f, 0.0, 1.0)
hist(q, freq=FALSE, add=TRUE)
```

and it produces graph like one below, looks good to me

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right, but what to consider g(x) when considering C as you showed?

Comment: @adam your code does not follow rules of the rejection sampling - your PDFs were not normalized properly.